# Codeigniter app returning 404 error on moving the files to root directory

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

I have setup my codeigniter website on live server. It was working fine when it was inside a folder in root directory. But after moving files to root directory the website is returning 404 error.

Below is my base url in config.php.

i have tried changing the base url to the site address(example.com/) but its not working

$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

Comment: You have to make some changes in .htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|documentation|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Isn't because you were programming in Windows at your machine, but the server runs Linux, and there are differences in folders names with a starting or not capital letter? In Linux `/images` and `/Images` are totally different and not related folders.